# CSS: em or ex for number width?

Tags: css, font-size

I have to set the width of an input field such as it fits 2 numbers (e.g. from 00 to 99).
I tried `width:2em` but it is too large, `width:2ex' and it is too small...

Which unit is best to use? Is there any standard practice?

**EDIT**

I know that proportional fonts make width calculation difficult, but usually numbers have fixed width to allow alignment of digits. So I figured out there were some unit to deal with them...

e.g. the following 10-digits random sequences (in proportional font) have the same width...

1234567890

3421434234

2324235252

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One `em` is the maximum character-width of the current font (the width of an upper-case M). One `ex` is about half the height of the current font (the height of the lower-case x).

Sadly, if you aren't using a monospaced font (one where all the letters take up the same amount of horizontal space, such as Courier), the width of a certain combination of letters will not be the same as every other combination of as many letters.

Example:

Stack Overflow does not use a monospaced font for its comments, hence these following lines are of different width, though containing the same amount of letters:

iiiiiiiii
MMMMMMMMM

However, if I write in a monospaced font, they *do* occupy the same horizontal width:

```
iiiiiiiii
MMMMMMMMM
```

Comment: I know, but usually numbers have fixed width to allow number alignement. So I figured out there were some unit to deal with them...

Comment: Perhaps you could figure out what fraction of an `em` a number is in your font of choice. But no, there's no unit specifically for the width of numbers, because frankly there's no guarantee that numbers will have the same width if you aren't using a monospace font. Just look at Comic Sans.

Comment: 1 em is not the width of the m unit in CSS. This is FALSE. It is the height of its parents font. Ex is the width of the x character, not the height! This is a very misleading post. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-size#Ems

Comment: Some (many?) variable-spaced fonts actually do have the same character width for all numeric digits.